# What the 'N' means on the following N-gram approximation

Tags: natural-language, language-models

What the 'N'(capital) means in the following N-gram
approximation to the conditional probability of the next word in a sequence ?

[image]

Comment: Put the formula in context. Without that it is hard to discern what any of the symbols mean.

Answer (score 1):

$N$ in the equation corresponds to the N in N-gram. E.g. if you use bi-grams, $N=2$.